# Excel Novice. Need assistance creating a formula per below (if possible to do without VBA):

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 2 excel sheets.  1 marked Transactions with a column of various monthly bank/credit card transactions.  The other sheet is a mapping spreadsheet consisting of 2 columns, the first is a sub text (string?) of the transactions listed on the transaction sheet and the 2nd column is a transaction identifier.  I want a formula on transaction sheet, whereby any transaction listed with the string (sub text) in it would return the classificaiton on the mapping sheet. Is there a forumla for this without writing code that would apply to multiple transactions i.e. the entire columns?

[![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6JBt.png)

Comment: I gave up quickly in trying to follow. Can you post some screenshots? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi @Renata please [edit] your post and share some sample data from both sheets along with expected result, will make some scene and help me & others to fix the issue!!

Comment: @Rajesh S, thank you for your response.  I've updated to my post to add an image.  I hope this helps.  If not, please let me know, I'm happy to clarify.  Thanks so much for taking the time to look at my post and try to help.

Comment: @ Ack, I've added an image that I hope helps to clarify.  Thanks for trying to help.  Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Hi @user13091661,, now check my post I've solved the issue,, I think this is what U are looking for !

Answer (score 0):

*Lookup formula with `SEARCH` and wrapped with `IFERROR` solves the issue:*

[image]

**How it works:**

- It's like partial match in Column.
- Formula in cell `L31`:

  ```
  =IFERROR(LOOKUP(9.99999999999999E+307,SEARCH(Mapping!$M$31:$M$39,K31),Mapping!$N$31:$N$39),"")
  ```

**N.B.**

- `9.99999999999999E+307`, considered as the biggest number (length) could have in any column and it's used to return `Row Number` of the    searched value within the INDEX range, and helps  formula to find and return the value.
- The `SEARCH` function returns the location of one text string inside another.
- *You need to adjust Sheet name & cell references in the formula as needed.*

Answer (score -1):

Yes, that clarifies nicely.

You cannot reliably do what you wish to do as the material stands.

The basic problem is how does one connect a thing like "TOYOTA CREDIT  RLS" to "LEXUS FINANCIAL  RLS"? Of course, one COULD do it with long and complicated formulas but then that word "reliably" comes into play. And after that consideration, this data has the feel of the load of cr*p data credit cards offer for download with the idea that one could easily then have many months worth of data to comb through and why does it match this thing on a nearby row rather than this other thing a couple more rows off, or 263 rows off?

The 2nd sheet might be called the mapping sheet but if so, that's not because it does any mapping. Nor does it really enable mapping. What would be handy would be a structure in which the first sheet is as it is, perhaps, and the second sheet has THREE columns:  a column with the EXACT material in the first sheet's first column, then the two current columns. The idea would be to add the first sheet's data, see if any errors present themselves, and act accordingly. Errors? Yes, you'd have a column of lookups where the codes go (the lookups would be how those codes got to sheet one).

If any errors popped up, it would mean those lines' items were not in the list on sheet two. So you'd add them, right then, filling in the second and third columns on sheet two for them. Once the errors were taken care of, you'd be good to go. No errors? Means there's nothing new and you can move on after adding the data. (The lookup formula will fill in the code column for you.)

Pitfall? Making sure the table one refers to in the lookup is never smaller than the full amount of material on sheet two! Have it written to include a few dozen extra rows, or a few hundred. So when you paste new material on and fill out the line, it's still in the table. Check on it every now and then. OR, better, use a dynamic reference formula to make the table always perfect, always exact.

Looking at it though, it's hard to see the need for the existing column A on the mapping sheet. Doesn't seem useful. But it won't hurt to keep it if it is.

An alternative would be to make that column have material that more usefully connects it to the first sheet's column A. That might make direct lookups more possibly reliable. If not, well, not. But if it makes lookups really hard to impossible in a practical world, then it doesn't seem much use to actually mapping anything.

Long and complicated? Well, one approach for each lookkup might be to write nested `FIND()`, `SEARCH()`, or `SUBSTITUTE()` formulas that take a piece of the first sheet's entry and looks in every column of the second sheet for it until some match is found. But that's a huge undertaking even for a max of 20 characters in the input data and if "Toyota" (for example) is found in two different kinds of entries, not just one kind (like a car payment and maintenance for the car both having "Toyota" in their text), the the reliablility issue arises as it might return the wrong on.

My favorite nowadays is using `MID()` with `SEQUENCE()` taking a string one character at a time, or two, or sixteen, etc. at a time and using the text produced. Most useful in the one at a time use, but this could use them all to test pieces against the second sheet, all quintinliyhuge-illion possibilities... or choke the computer each time you open the file...

Oh, the lookups I refer to would be the standard things, probably the nice new `XLOOKUP()` now. All those tests I mentioned above? The quintinliyhuge-illion possibilities? Each would have to be fed into the lookup chosen so the first successful one would have a result that you'd use. So twice that many operations, or more...

Bottom line? Looks a ton like the material has to be restructured.

Doesn't matter much if it is not yours and you do not even load the data. You can still restructure while doing your work. Keep a second file with the table I described. Have formulas on that or another sheet in it that do the actual lookup up. Then copy and paste their results (`Copy|Paste|Special:  Values`) back into the current spreadsheet where they belong. You did an end run around the designer's idea of perfection. They never know as it doesn't change their spreadsheet and yet they get the results they wanted. Win-Win.

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User! We are always glad to help, but you apparently have two Super User accounts: [this one](https://superuser.com/users/1153011/jeorje) and [this one](https://superuser.com/users/1153366/jeorje). Please take the time to utilize the following Help Center tutorial and ask the Super User staff to merge your accounts: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts)